# Simplify Inverse Trigonometry Expressions

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

Help! I need to simplify this expression. I'm not even sure where to start.

$$
\tan{(\arccos{(\frac{x}{4})})}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let  $\displaystyle y=\tan\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\right)\;,$ Now Put $\displaystyle \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)=\phi\;,$

Then $\displaystyle \frac{x}{4} = \cos \phi\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \sec \phi = \frac{4}{x},$ So using $\displaystyle \tan \phi = \pm \sqrt{\sec^2 \phi -1} = \pm \frac{\sqrt{16-x^2}}{x}$

So We get $\displaystyle y = \tan \phi = \pm \frac{\sqrt{16-x^2}}{x}$

Comment: If $0 < x \leq 4$, then $0 < \arccos(x/4) \leq \pi/2$, so $\tan[\arccos(x/4)] = \frac{\sqrt{16 - x^2}}{x} > 0$.  If $-4 \leq x < 0$, then $\pi/2 < x \leq \pi$, so $\tan[\arccos(x/4)] = \frac{\sqrt{16 - x^2}}{x} < 0$.  Therefore, there should not be a $\pm$ in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

HINT...draw a right-angled triangle with adjacent side $x$ and hypotenuse $4$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\arccos\frac{x}{4} = \theta$

This implies $$\frac{x}{4} = \cos \theta $$

Forming a right angled triangle with the above and using pythagoras' theorem, opposite side to angle $\theta$ will be: $\pm\sqrt{16-x^2}$.

Therefore,

$$\tan \theta = \tan \left(\arccos \frac{x}{4}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{16-x^2}}{x} $$

Comment: If $0 < x \leq 4$, then $0 < \arccos(x/4) \leq \pi/2$, so $\tan[\arccos(x/4)] = \frac{\sqrt{16 - x^2}}{x} > 0$.  If $-4 \leq x < 0$, then $\pi/2 < x \leq \pi$, so $\tan[\arccos(x/4)] = \frac{\sqrt{16 - x^2}}{x} < 0$.  Therefore, there should not be a $\pm$ in your answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, thanks for pointing this out.